# Add XML extension on project build path in Eclipse not working

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, maven

[image]

I have added XML extension in my `Java Build Path` , but when I am running `mvn test` it is showing error

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] F:\HibernateExample\src\main\java\net\dibyendu\hibernate\Main.java:[53,16]  error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 1 error
```

Also when I am trying to `Run As` `Java Application` I am not getting the my `main class` to execute .

Here is my Main.java file coding:

```
package net.dibyendu.hibernate;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Read
    System.out.println("******* READ *******");
    List employees = list();
    System.out.println("Total Employees: " + employees.size());


    // Write
    System.out.println("******* WRITE *******");
    Employee empl = new Employee("Jack", "Bauer", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), "911");
    empl = save(empl);

}



private static List list() {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    List employees = session.createQuery("from Employee").list();
    session.close();
    return employees;
}
private static Employee read(Long id) {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, id);
    session.close();
    return employee;
}
private static Employee save(Employee employee) {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    Long id = (Long) session.save(employee);
    employee.setId(id);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();

    return employee;
}

private static Employee update(Employee employee) {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    session.merge(employee);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();
    return employee;

}

private static void delete(Employee employee) {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    session.delete(employee);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();
}

}
```

I am getting plenty of error keeping the error line in `try catch` :

```
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.5.5-Final
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : src/main/resources/Employee.hbm.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: src/main/resources/Employee.hbm.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at net.dibyendu.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
at net.dibyendu.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
at net.dibyendu.hibernate.Main.list(Main.java:31)
at net.dibyendu.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:17)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource:  src/main/resources/Employee.hbm.xml not found
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:665)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1679)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1647)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1626)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1600)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1520)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1506)
at net.dibyendu.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
... 3 more
```

I am very new to `hibernate` so please guide me.

Comment: provide us with some code.

Comment: @Henrik , what code you want me to provide?

Comment: Main.java:[53,16]  error: cannot find symbol which line is this?

Comment: This is the [53,16] `employee.setId(id);` in the `private static Employee save(Employee employee) { `

Comment: Can you do it in a try and catch and provide the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Very nice to tell Eclipse that you've added the xml files to the classpath, but you haven't told Maven. Maven divides classpath files into 2 groups: compilable (under `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`) and non-compilable aka resources ( under `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`). The preferred solution is to move these xml files to the proper folder. When using m2eclipse, just update the project and eclipse will add these sourcefolders for you.
Btw. this doesn't explain the compilation error, this is just one of the issues you're facing.